# Is there an easy way to implement an Active Sync protocol to share contact and calendar details without using Exchange server

Tags: exchange-server, activesync, owncloud

I am a newbie in exchange. I want to implement exchange of data using Active Sync protocol without Exchange server.

Basically, I want to share my database contact with customer. so when then sync with server all my Database contact will be added to their mobile or outlook. I can't use the Exchange server due to licensing problem.

I am getting some solution to use Horde. I do not have complex requirement of security just need to sync data of DB to phone or outlook.

Edited : 12/31/2013
Actually I was searching for some alternative to Exchange protocol because it's licensed to MS. Found CalDAV and CardDAV protocol which I implemented using OwnCloud

Comment: The Exchange ActiveSync protocol must be licensed from Microsoft before you sell a product based on it. So get your lawyers spooled up.

Comment: Actually I was searching for some alternative to Exchange protocol because it's licensed to MS. Found CalDAV and CardDAV protocol which I implemented using OwnCloud